# This email address does not belong to the same domain as the site-ContactForm7

Tags: wordpress, email, contact-form-7

> This email address does not belong to the same domain as the site.

the syntax is…

`[your-name] <[your-email]>`

It's working good If I am use that syntax,
`[your-name] <xyz@gmail.com>`

I need to put email(`xyz@gmail.com`) as user fill a FORM.

Thanks to all!

Comment: you should set some value or [your-name] before the <xyz@gmail.com>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't set the from field to the user's email address; it has to come from your site's domain. Use the Reply-To header for that instead.

From: `[your-name] <manually enter email here>`

Additional Headers: `Reply-To: [your-email]`

Further reading: http://contactform7.com/best-practice-to-set-up-mail/

Comment: Thanks for your answer!